# Retrofit2 en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Quiero implementar Retrofit en Kotlin y estoy teniendo inconvenientes para leer la respuesta que obtengo de la API.

Esto devuelve mi API

```
{"result":true,"status":"success"}
```

El problema es en la lectura, al parecer

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var response:Boolean = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getRetrofit()

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {

            getResponse()
            Toast.makeText(this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.43.243:2001/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun getResponse() {
        doAsync {
            val call = getRetrofit().create(APIService::class.java).getResponse().execute()
            val res = call.body() as APIResponse
            uiThread {
                if(res.status == "success") {
                    response = res.response

                }else{
                    //showErrorDialog()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Siempre arroja "False" sin poder asignar a la variable 'response' el valor "true" en este caso. ¿Tienen alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el código, el método getResponse() parece que no está  mal.  Lo que ocurre es que cuando ejecutas el click del botón btnLogin, se llama al método getResponse() y se ejecuta el Toast que muestra false porque dentro del click listener las acciones son síncronas, de hecho si la response la declaras como latenit te dará error porque no se llega a inicializar.  Es decir, el Toast se muestra antes de actualizar o iniciar el valor de la response. Dado que no tienes arquitectura y estás realizando todo en la misma activity puedes mover el Toast al uiTread:

```
private fun getResponse() {
doAsync {
    val call = getRetrofit().create(APIService::class.java).getResponse().execute()
    val res = call.body() as APIResponse
    uiThread {
        if (isSuccess) showMessage()
        else showError()
    }
}
```